# Ext JS: How to select a combobox item within item's root/index value?

Tags: javascript, select, extjs, combobox

I've created a `combobox` with Ext JS and it's doing `proxy` request with `Ajax` to display items. All works fine but the thing I need to write a query to be able select items of combobox with indexed number value.

I mean! I can do selection as this way so fine with `textEqual` query:

```
#main-home #contentPanel #formData combobox[name=...combo] boundlist => :textEquals(The Item Name)
```

but items are changing to fast so I want to be able to select the first item of `combobox` and looking for a query syntax such as:

```
#main-home #contentPanel #formData combobox[name=...combo] boundlist => :root(1)
```

or

```
#main-home #contentPanel #formData combobox[name=...combo] boundlist => :index(1)
```

Any idea to achieve this selection/query?
Thanks in advice...

Comment: What version of ExtJS do you work on?

Comment: @foxdie Ext JS version is 6.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign an identifier to the combo box :

```
{ // Combobox
    xtype   :   'combo',
    action  :   'actionComboBox',
    ............
    id      :   'comboboxId' // <= Here
},
```

Then use the ID :

```
var combobox = Ext.getCmp("comboboxId");
```

After if you want to take the value for exemple just use :

```
var comboboxValue = combobox.getValue();
```

Comment: Isn't there any chance to use component query for selection?

Comment: With the manipulation of identifiers, you can recover the content that is sent by your combobox and exploit it with methods like `getValues()`. It's easier like that ExtJs 6.5.0 simplifies things. By using componement query I'm afraid it is more complicated.